# Enviar parámetros de consulta con los botones exportar de Datatables

Tags: laravel-5, datatables

Estoy usando DataTables 7.0 con laravel 5.4.15, Tengo una tabla que quiero mostrar con DataTable, por lo que creé dos campos de fechas para filtrar la consulta inicial para que no me traiga los miles de registros que pueda llegar a tener la tabla. Hasta aqui todo bien, el problema esta que al usar los botones de exportar, estos vuelven a ejecutar la consulta para tomar los datos y exportarlos, pero no envían los campos de filtro, por lo que no hace nada ya que en la función query() estoy pidiendo esos datos.

esta es la clase que uso.

```
namespace App\DataTables;
use App\Accesos;
use Yajra\Datatables\Services\DataTable;

class AccesosDataTable extends DataTable
{

public function ajax()
{   

    return $this->datatables
    ->eloquent($this->query())
    ->make(true);

}


public function html()
{
    return $this->builder()
            ->columns($this->getColumns())
                ->ajax('')
            ->parameters([
                'dom'          => 'Bfrtip',  
                'buttons'      => ['export', 'reload'],
            ]);
}

public function query()
{
    $key = $this->attributes;
    $users = Accesos::whereBetween('field_filter',[$key['from'].' 00:00:00',$key['to'].' 23:59:59'])->select();

    return $this->applyScopes($users);

}

protected function getColumns()
{
    return [
        'field1',
        'field2',
        'field3',
        'field4',
        'field5',
        'field6',
    ];
}

protected function filename()
{
     return strtolower(trans('accesos'));
}
```

}

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow en Español. Te invito a que conozcas como funciona la comunidad visitando la presentación (http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). A continuación, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta siguiendo las directrices de calidad (http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).